# Level too difficult: nerfed

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I remember reading that a particular level on Candy Crush received a flood of complaints, so King made it easier. Did this happen, and which level was it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nerfing or buffing are also called Redesigning, and this happens all the time with many different levels. So the answer for your question is yes, but not just one particular level.

From Candy Crush Saga wikia

> Every now and then, when too many people complain that a level is too
>   difficult and many players reach the level and quit, the Candy Crush
>   team will redesign the level to make it a little easier, or a lot
>   easier in some cases.

There are many levels have been redesigned (including both nerfed and buffed). For the full list, you can have a look [here](http://candy-crush-saga.wikia.com/wiki/Redesigning).